# Multiple Custom user model authentication using Djangorestframework-simplejwt

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-framework-simplejwt

I am working on a multitenant application, which I have applied authentication using Djangorestframework-simplejwt. I want to have several custom user models(Staff,Student,Admin) authentication using Djangorestframework-simplejwt. Any ideas on how to implement it will be deeply appreciated